# Firefox, how to get Add-on back in Toolbar after removing it?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I right clicked an Add-on (uBlock) that was in the toolbar and selected "Remove from Toolbar" now how do I put it back? Add-on is still installed just not in toolbar.

--Customize screen, no Add-ons.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> how do I put it back?

All you need to do is the following:

1. Right-Click on the toolbar and select **Customize**.
2. Drag and Drop the **uBlock** icon to your toolbar.

Comment: I tried this but there are no addons in the customize screen only the default Firefox icons. I have added a screenshot.

Comment: I removed the exact add-on your asking about, using the same option before I submitted my answer, what I described should have worked.

Comment: see the screenshot its not there.

Comment: @mbwasi, not sure what your situation is but Ramhound is certainly right that that is how it should show up (see the way it is by me https://imgur.com/jsdhTLn). Possible that you have Firefox set to "Never Remeber History" (Always Private Browsing) and this Addon is not allowed in Private Browsing? Can you share a screenshot of this addon's manage page?

Comment: ended up uninstalling and reinstalling it to get it back